# is there a generic way to check if time is synchronised

Tags: ntp

I am writing some software that runs on a system that may or may not have access to the internet and I want it to behave differently depending on whether the clock is synchronised, It will likely run on a Debian-based distro, but exactly which one and which version and hence which time sync daemon is in use may vary.

Is there a way to check if time is synchronised that works across multiple time-sync implementations? (ideally at least ntpd, chronyd and systemd-timesyncd).

Comment: I'd settle for "has it synced at least once since system boot", though more granularity could be useful.

Comment: @p It would be good if it gave some indication in the form of an atomic hash proving the actual syncronization occurred with further proof, ideally a timestamped hash proven also with some blockchain, so I do not need to trust my ISP is not hacked/backdoored by my NTPServer. Right now I am being investigated by some "police" who are aggressively without question changing my time shown inthe computer clock at the upper right on all Mac/Win/Lin machines, and proving that requires too much work for the average user, making the game a con about who can prove the time not a legal case a clock hack.